The "stained glass window problem": Draw many random chords in a circle; which kind of polygon ($3$-gon, $4$-gon, etc.) occupies the most total area?
Draw $n$ random chords in a circle, where each chord connects two independent uniformly random points on the circle.

As $n\to\infty$, which kind of polygon (triangle, quadrilateral, pentagon, etc.) occupies the most total area?

In the following examples, the polygons are color-coded.
$n=15$:

$n=20$:

$n=30$:

Triangles seem to be the most numerous, but smallest (in terms of average size). As the number of sides increases, the polygons seem to get fewer, but bigger.
I guess that, as $n\to\infty$, one kind of polygon should emerge as the most dominant, in terms of total area.
I made a random chord generator. Unfortunately, it does not color-code the polygons. (For the examples shown above, I color-coded the polygons manually.)

Context: This is another question of mine about many random chords in a circle. Earlier questions are here and here.

Empirically it seems to be pentagons. Out of $1000$ trials of $5m$ chords for $m \in [1, 20]$ pentagons took the lead at $20$ chords with $416$ wins (vs $395$ for quadrilaterals), and by $100$ chords they were winning more than $80%$ of trials, with quadrilaterals picking up the rest.

Wouldn't the fraction of the area covered by $d$-gons converge as $n\to\infty$ to the side distribution $p_d$ of the Crofton cell of the Poisson line process? See the summary of Hilhorst & Calka in Section 1.2 of arXiv:0802.1869, which claims that $p_d$ has mean $\pi^2/2=4.93\ldots$ and peaks at pentagons $d=5$, citing Matheron.

@TimothyBudd Is the side distribution of the Crofton cell the same as the side distribution of a typical cell?

No, see the same paragraph of the paper Hilhorst & Calka. The Crofton cell is biased by the area, compared to the typical cell.
